# Show message when AWS EMR step has finished

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, cluster-computing

When running a step (for example loading data) on my AWS EMR cluster via the terminal, is it possible to automatically return a message in my terminal when the step has finished? Instead of having to check it myself every several minutes?

Comment: AWS cluster? assume its EMR cluster - you can describe cluster status using aws-cli more info http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/describe-cluster.html

Comment: Yes, EMR cluster. But I don't want to perform the describe function every few minutes to see the status.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can only [`wait`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/wait/index.html) for the EMR cluster to terminate using `aws-cli`. If you need status of each tasks, I think you need to write something custom. May be the `Cloudwatch` can be a choice as well. As there are EMR metrics by default sent to cloudwatch. More details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html#UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics_MetricsReported). Hope this helps.